# PDO & custom Database wrapper class: static or instance?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I was looking for a good PDO wrapper class in PHP; as no class among those I have seen suited my needs, I decided to write my own one, enhancing a class I already wrote before that used the now-dreaded `mysql_*` functions to integrate the native escaping, db-agnosticity, prepared statements and so on.

One thing I was wondering is, what is the best approach in developing and using a class like this? One alternative would be by instances:

```
$db = new Database();
$db->query("SELECT this FROM that");
```

The other would be with static methods:

```
DB::query("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE answer=42");
```

I've seen some frameworks (f.ex. Joomla API) that prefer to use the first method, but I am not sure of which could be the possible pitfalls of the second approach.

Have you got any insights?

Comment: If you do not use a static context for this, you have a much easier life with unit testing so I'd suggest to use the first way. However I would even suggest to use a ORM like Doctrine2.

Comment: The first is usually prefered, because 1) static is hard to unit test and 2) there's the possibility to connect to two different databases, which although rare, it can happen, and the best way to handle that is just having two different Database instances.

Comment: With the static approach you'd have to create a bunch of methods to map all the PDO ones. Using an instance you don't and you'd get better IDE support.

Comment: @bcmcfc - any proof you get better IDE support or is it from ontop of your head?

Comment: @N.B. just from experience using phpStorm. No in depth studies to link you to.

Comment: @bcmcfc - fair enough, might be worth saying which IDE benefits from it then in the initial comment :)

Comment: Come on. Another one of these questions? There's TONS of information out there about design and instances vs static. Go read and your decision will be made for you...

Comment: @ircmaxell Found nothing useful till now (at last, and I am quite good on googling). I'm sorry if the question felt stupid or redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally don't see the need for a PDO wrapper class (PDO is a database wrapper class in on itself).

However, if you wish to do it, do it as an instance, for several reasons:

1. It makes more sense, you may want more than one database connection.
2. It's easier to use.
3. It uses less global space, **[which is evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)**.
4. It makes me happy.

So yeah, instance is the way to go, although I would just use native PDO for most tasks.

Comment: The need is to have a more structured approach to some data (with particular custom operations and classes), it integrates better with the framework I'm developing.

Comment: @Cranio: PDO's structure makes sense. You have the PDO object, which is a connection object, and a PDOStatement object which is an object to describe a statement (basically a query). I still don't see the need for change, but as I stated with my answer, if you must, that's the way to go.

Comment: Anything to make the Truth happy.

Comment: @deceze: Unless you want to meet The Gate.

Comment: @Cranio: You might be less looking for the database adapter, but how you do the data-mapping. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JRjML.jpg

Answer (score -3):

A static instance of a database class is handy as instead of having to pass the object into functions/methods as a parameter or call `global($db)` you can simply call `$db = Database::instance()` and instead of instantiating a new object you have access to the singleton.

Just depends how you want your application to work.

Comment: the singleton approach is exactly what I have used until now. But I saw very frequently the non static approach and was wondering why...

Comment: Yeah, [**no**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what).

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It's actually not bad. Static one is handy if one wants to have `getInstance()` available instead of doing DI or whatever you wanna call it. This answer just listed two possibilities, it didn't cover all of them but I think anyone with a bit of intelligence can grasp the meaning of it.

Comment: @N.B.: Static is no different than normal functions. It's procedural, which brings it down to the level of procedural mysqli and mysql_*. Database connections are classic OOP.

Comment: @Cranio it's really up to you. I like to have a central object (kernel class in some frameworks) it holds all my common object which I pass into a class when instantiated so it has access to the common objects. It's really just a matter of preference

Comment: @Truth - They're not. Nor is object oriented programming anything special except a way of managing code. All code is "procedural", one instruction executed at a time by CPU, regardless of how initial source is transformed by compiler or interpreter. So your comment is false, and downvoting a proper answer is just plain stupid. The distinction is mentioned here, you can either use a singleton and invoke its `getInstance()` method (which is handy) or you can do dependency injection / make the db object global or whatever other method you prefer.

Comment: @N.B.: How is making the database object global handy? You have no idea what changes it, what a function can do with it, or what kind of database it's connected to if it changes at some point.

Comment: You know what really handy is? A global variable. It beats static in miles. Static is for those who want to look cool for their friends.

Comment: @Truth - it's handy because you don't have to worry about CREATING it, passing it around and anything can access it and I am not **advocating** any approach here unlike you, everything has its upsides and downsides. Just because there's a bullet in the gun, it doesn't mean you're stupid enough to shoot yourself in the head. Same applies here - there's no perfect design, saying one thing sucks without adding context is incredibly bad. I'm arguing that this answer was donwvoted only on the basis of showing an example where static *COULD* be used.

Comment: @Truth - I'm sorry but I really don't like programming zealots and fanatics who like using big words to describe trivial things. Object oriented programming sounds nice and dandy, but it's just a way of forcing people to code in a structured, maintainable way. It's not a revolution in "thinking" as people in white coats who write bullshit books tend to make it, it's simply enforcing a protocol and attitude towards coding. In the end, programmer making spaghetti code using procedural / static can do the same with OOP.

Comment: @N.B. You still have to worry about creating/importing/initializing it, and contrary to injected instances it's harder to manage because the instantiation is so implicit instead of explicit.